# Index required for basic joins on foreign key that references a primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about a fundamental aspect of PostgreSQL.

Suppose I have two tables along the lines of the following:

```
create table source_data_property (
  source_data_property_id integer primary key generated by default as identity,
  property_name text not null
);

create table source_data_value (
  source_data_value_id integer primary key generated by default as identity,
  source_data_property_id integer not null references source_data_property,
  data_value numeric not null
);
```

Suppose I write a very simple query that just performs a basic join:

```
select 
  sdp.source_data_property_id,
  sdp.property_name,
  sdv.source_data_value_id,
  sdv.data_value
from source_data_property as sdp
join source_data_value as sdv using (source_data_property_id)
;
```

For optimal query performance, is it necessary to add an index on the `source_data_property_id` column in the `source_data_value` table?  My original thought was **no**, because the `source_data_property_id` is already indexed in the `source_data_property` table, but after thinking about it a bit I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For optimal query performance, is it necessary to add an index on the source_data_property_id column in the source_data_value table?

In general yes, make indexes for your foreign keys. However...

A very small table won't get any advantage from indexes and Postgres will do a seq scan instead.

Similarly it depends on what sort of queries you're doing. In your example you're fetching every row in source_data_property which will also fetch every row in source_data_value. Using an index is slower and Postgres will do a seq scan instead.